# Disqus Comment Count Not Always Passing URL with AJAX

Tags: ajax, disqus

Basically in a nut shell I'm using AJAX to pass through say 30 items in an infinite scroll/masonry setup. In my AJAX file, one of the lines basically is requesting the WEB URL + the Unique Key for the page + the Disqus Hash Tag at the end to get the comment count for the page and to display this on the index. E.g. it looks like this

http://url.com?id=".$row['pkey']."#disqus_thread\">

For some reason, I'm getting mixed results. Sometimes, I will get results for all of the items as I scroll down and they load with masonry. Other times I will get no comment count and it will simply be blank for all of the items loaded via masonry. It's very sporadic and doesn't always pass the value through.

I know I could use the API and do some more complicated things, but for my purpose I'm simply looking to get a post count for the relevant URL and display it, that's all.

Any tips on why this passes and other times it does not? Everything else in my page seems in order.

Comment: Just an FYI, on the same item I also am using the "pkey" to link to the page and that works fine 100% of the time, so I know it's not an issue with that value...

Comment: Again, any thoughts? This seems completely random. Sometimes it passes them, sometimes it does not...

Comment: Were you able to fix it? Please share